# How to not care about class member template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have two classes:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class foo{
    //something here
}

class bar{
    bar()=delete;
    bar(const foo& a): a(a){}
private:
    foo a;
}
```

This code will not work.

But, how can I achieve something like it?

I know that I should tell what is the type of the used `foo`. But in real, I do not allow default constructor. So, I can not make an object of `bar` without giving it the suitable `foo`.. Why I have to tell the compiler what is the `T1` and `T2` then?

Comment: "Why I have to tell the compiler what is the T1 and T2 then?" Because as Stephan Lavavej said templates are like cookie cutters, you can make delicious cookies out of them but you cannot eat them.

Comment: What about making `bar` class template ? Like `template<class T1, class T2> class bar { ... private: foo<T1,T2> a; }` ?

Comment: "I do not allow default constructor" - what does that mean?

Comment: What @DragonRock said, plus make a function `make_bar(Foo)` that frees you from having to specify `T1` and `T2` when creating a `Bar` from a `Foo`.

Comment: @Default it is not personal really :D... just joking.. I mean that three is no chance that 'foo a;' will be default inilized wihtout knowing what is T1 and T2

Comment: @nwp if I got you , you are trying to imitate the std:make_pair or sth like it?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes. `std::unique_ptr` has the same problem and uses `std::make_unique` for the same reason (plus for consistency with `std::make_shared`).

Comment: @nwp thanks it seems beautiful and nice idea. However, I still do not why it could not be automatically process while there is no missing ring

Comment: `foo` is not a type and hence no variable of 'type' `foo` can ever exist. You must accept a valid type.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi check out my answer. It should make it a bit clearer *why* the type of a data member can't be deduced automatically.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data member can have exactly one type. `foo` is not a type. It's a template. You cannot leave the deduction of the type of the member to the compiler. That's simply not possible in c++. †

You can also not pass a reference to `foo`  to the constructor because again,  `foo` is not a type.

What you need is polymorphism.

DragonRock shows how to achieve static polymorphism with templates: Define `bar` to be a class template. Then you can parametrize the type of the member using the template parameters. You still need to specify the template parameters explicitly, so they won't be deduced by the call to the constructor. However, you can then write function template that returns an object with a type that is specific instance of `bar` with the template parameters depending on the template parameters of the function. The template parameters of the function can be deduced from the parameter that is passed to it.

Walter shows how to achieve dynamic polymorphism with inheritance: Define all `foo` instances to have a common base class. Then store a reference or a pointer of that base class type in `bar`.

† *Why doesn't the standard allow deducing the type of the data member form the call to the constructor?* You may ask. Well let's assume that your example is valid c++. Now consider this code:

```
bar& b = get_me_a_bar();
auto f = b.foo;
```

What is the type of `f`? There is no call to the constructor of `bar` in this code, so it can't be deduced from that. Nevertheless, the type of `f` must be known. Sure, there must be a call to the constructor in `get_me_a_bar` or somewhere else, but the call could be in another compilation unit. It would make compilation slower by `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of compilation units, to look for the calls to the constructor. What if the compilation units that call the constructor haven't been compiled yet? This sort of deduction would create dependencies on what order the units are compiled.

TL;DR C++ is a statically typed language. In statically typed languages the type of a variable must be know at compile time, whenever that variable is used. The uses of a member variable don't necessarily coincide with the uses of the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is to write your `bar` classs as a template class. And as [@nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693670/how-to-not-care-about-class-member-template#comment-55159049) suggested, you could make a `make_bar` function as a helper to avoid expliciting your types when creating a `bar` from a `foo`, like so :

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class foo {
    //something here
};

template<class T1, class T2>
class bar {
    public:
        bar()=delete;
        bar(const foo<T1,T2>& a): a(a){}
    private:
        foo<T1, T2> a;
};

template<class T1, class T2>
bar<T1, T2> make_bar(foo<T1,T2> const& f) {
    return bar<T1, T2>{f};
}

int main() {

    auto myFoo = foo<int, double>{};
    auto barintdouble = make_bar(myFoo);

}
```

Comment: Thanks I used your implementation to solve my problem. However, your very nice post did not answer directly my question so I did not accept it as the answer although I learned a new thing from it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes very little sense: it is not clear what your data member `bar::foo a` is meant to represent. Depending on what you really want to achieve (which you failed to explain), this could be an object of a *specific* type `foo<T1,T2>`, or it could be an object of *any* `foo<T1,T2>` type. In the former case, you must also make `bar` specific, i.e. a class template, as suggested in other answers.

However, if any `foo<T1,T2>` is fine, then you must use polymorphism.

```
class base_foo {
  virtual void func() const = 0; // etc.
  virtual~base_foo() {}
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class foo : public base_foo
{
  void func() const override;
};
```

Now you can refer to any `foo<T1,T2>` via its base `base_foo`, but you cannot easily hold an actual object in `bar`. The way that most closely reflects your initial code is to store a real `foo<T1,T2>` on the heap, but access it via a pointer to `base_foo`.

```
class bar
{
  std::unique<base_foo> ptr;
public:
  template<typename T1,typename T2>
  bar(foo<T1,T2> const&obj)
  : ptr(new foo<T1,T2>(obj)) {}       // calls foo<T1,T2>::foo<T1,T2>(foo<T1,T2> const&)
};
```

which makes a copy of the original object as in your code.